# What is the usual single letter flag denoting an IP address in a commandline option?

Tags: bash, command-line, parameter, conventions

I noticed in most programs that I use that read in IP addresses, they either use no option flag to denote IP address and it is just part of the default input (like ssh, scp, ifconfig, etc...) or it is like IPtables where it's the source IP or destination IP.  But I'd imagine there are some programs where the IP address is a named parameter.

I just would like to know what that name usually (long and short if it exists) is so I can use it in my scripts and not confuse people.

Comment: There is no convention, as you have noticed. It totally depends on the application and the role of the host argument on the command line.  For "long options", `--host=hostname/ipaddr` may be a good choice, but that's personal opinion, and similarly `-h` as a short option.

Comment: @Kusalananda I wouldn't recommend -h as a short option, that's far too commonly `--help`. Your comment seems like an answer...

Answer (score 3):

There is no convention, as you have noticed. It totally depends on what the application is doing and the role of the host argument on the command line, as well as how applications related to your script does it. Hence, the answer to this is most likely to be opinion-based.

For "long options", `--host=hostname` may be a good choice, but that's personal opinion, and similarly `-h` as a short option.  This is the way MySQL/MariaDB and the PostgreSQL command line clients does it.

As Derobert points out in the comments to your question, `-h` for a hostname may collide with the use of `-h` for getting help, but `-?`, `--help`, or running the application with *no* arguments, is sometimes used for that.

It may also be useful to indicate what the hostname that goes with a particular option is used for, such as `--target=hostname` and `--jumphost=hostname` etc.  If you want to indicate that the host need to be an IP address (and not a hostname), one could possibly use `--addr=ipaddr` or something similar. Some tools use `-T` and `-U` for specifying what bind address to use with TCP and UDP sockets respectively (specifically `syslogd` on OpenBSD). Again, this comes down to what your script is actually doing.

If your shell script uses several options to modify its behaviour while *always* operating on a hostname, then don't use an option to specify the hostname, like `ssh` does.

In the end, look at how similar utilities are managing their command line flags and go with something that is consistent. This is especially important if you're building a set of multiple scripts for doing tasks that are related.  I.e., don't use `--host=hostname` in one while you have `-i addr` in another.